# What is JavaScript shorthand property?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = { prop = [1,2,3] };
```

The code above contains a typo, there should be a colon instead of `=`. But what surprised me was the VM error message:

```
var obj = { prop = [1,2,3] };
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

I searched for "JavaScript shorthand properties" but this term is still not clear to me. What does "Shorthand property" means in context of this error message?

Comment: `=` is only used to assign variable, not properties.. Replace `=` to `:`

Comment: @choz It's pretty obvious that the OP knows that given their first sentence: "The code above contains a typo, there should be a colon instead of `=`.".

Comment: @Paulpro Either it wasnt there before or i totally missed it..

Comment: If someone will search for "shorthand property" landing here could be a good thing because it is not obvious that shorthand property relates to the object literal.

Comment: @exebook I agree this useful not really a duplicate. {Q: "what is X?", A: "Y"} !== {Q: "What is Y", A: "X"}

Comment: @James that is exactly that kind of logic often missed by close voters

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With ES6, you can use shorthand property names which allow you to write something like this.

```
var s = 'abc';
var n = 1;
var o = { s, n }; // This is equivalent to { s: s, n: n }
```

In your case, `prop = [1,2,3]` was parsed as one shorthand property (`s` and `n` in the example above), but it was not a proper property name.

Comment: I don't think being an invalid property name has anything to do with it? Changing `prop` to anything else produces the same error.

Comment: You mean this is equivalent to `{ s: 'abc', n: 1 }` right?

Comment: @Jwan622 No. `{ s, n }` is syntactically equivalent to `{ s: s, n: n }`, and it will be evaluated to `{ s: 'abc', n: 1 }` in this context.

Answer (score 7):

Firefox has a different error message, which in my opinion is more useful:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

That is, there is a missing `:`. As you say, you should use `:` instead of `=`.

To make it clear, "shorthand property" has no meaning in the ES6 spec. It's just some expression Chrome invented to help you noticing your error. It seems they failed.

[snak's guess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948332/1529630) is that Chrome refers to a *PropertyDefinition* consisting of an *IdentifierReference*, used in an *ObjectLiteral*. Clearly `prop = [1,2,3]` is not an *IdentifierReference*, so it might make sense to complain about it. It would make even more sense to complain that it's not a *PropertyDefinition* in the much more common form of *PropertyName* `:` *AssignmentExpression*. Or *MethodDefinition*.

Comment: The question already states this: "The code above contains a typo, there should be a colon instead of =". The question is about why the error is worded that way.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Yes. You should read between the lines. My answer was an attempt to say "stop using a stupid browser like Chrome which gives such non-sense misleading error messages" in a polite way.

Comment: Ok, well that still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The question is "What does "Shorthand property" means in context of this error message?". The answer is "It's just some rubbish random message your browser decided to show there", other browsers use better messages.

Comment: They are commonly referred to as shorthand property initializers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Agree with the answer. It is the same error message with different wording.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli the referenced mdn article states a generic mean of object initialization, not this very error message, which seems -as Oriol claims- to be confined to chrome's lingo.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no official explanation from MDN I can only assume what this might mean.

Consider the following:

There are two ways of creating an array.

The long way (sort of):

```
var cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
```

The short way:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

The long and short way is more obvious when dealing with the creation of objects:

The long way:

```
var person = new Object();
person.firstName = "John";
person.lastName = "Doe";
```

The short way:

```
var person = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};
```