# why module.export { ...require('module') } work but not module.export { require('module') }

Tags: node.js

justExport.js

```
const first = () => {
  console.log('frist from justExport')
}

const second = () => {
  console.log('second fromt justExport')
}

module.exports = {
  first,
  second,
}
```

tmp.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...require('./justExport') // work
  require('./justExport') // SyntaxError: Unexpected string
}
```

main.js

```
const justExport = require('./justExport.js')
const tmp = require('./tmp.js')

console.log('Hello World!')
```

I have voluntarily create a fake example with the less possible code.

Comment: I just edited my post :)

Answer (score 2):

`{ ...require('./justExport') }` is [object literal spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). While `{ require('./justExport') }` is incorrect object literal syntax because it doesn't contain a key.

Unless the intention is to create shallow copy of `justExport` module, object literal isn't needed. It can be:

```
module.exports = require('./justExport');
```

Comment: How can I verify that require('./justExport') is an incorrect object ? Because I though that require() return an object create by module.export(), so if it's an object, it should contain a key/value notation right ? (tell me if I don't use the correct term or don't explain me well)

Comment: I didn't say its incorrect object. `{ require('./justExport') }` is incorrect *syntax*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer for all possible syntax variations. `require('./justExport')` expression is already an object. It doesn't need to be wrapped with braces.

Comment: I read the Syntax part of the link you posted. Does { require('./justExport') } is incorrect syntax because require return something like { key: value } but module.export expect something module.export { key { key: value } } ?

Comment: It's incorrect syntax because correct syntax is either `{ ...value }`, or `{ key: value }`, or `{ value }` (the latter is shorthand for `{ value: value }`). It doesn't matter what `require()` returns if you don't use correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify the answer from @estus, note that the following works due to [ES6 shorthand property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948306/what-is-javascript-shorthand-property):

```
const justExport = require('./justExport');

module.exports = {
  ...justExport, // works
  justExport // works because key is implicitly defined by variable name
}
```

Comment: Does module.exports { require('./justExport') } doesn't work because require return an object with any key that "point to that object  (return by require )?